# How to refactor link_to_function using unobustrive JS in helper?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, unobtrusive-javascript

I am using `link_to_function` in one of my `ApplicationHelper` method:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
  new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
    render(association.to_s + "_fields", :f => builder)
  end
  link_to_function(name, ("add_fields(this, '#{association}', '#{escape_javascript(fields)}')").html_safe)
end
```

Since it will be deprecated in Rails 4 I would like to get rid of `link_to_function` using Unobustrive JS. How to do that?

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617384/whats-the-best-ujs-way-of-refactoring-link-to-function

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was amused to run across this question with the exact same code snippet as I have... bless you Ryan Bates and RailsCasts!

In any case, this turns out to be a pretty easy refactor.  You just have to pass the function as the 'onclick' parameter of link_to:

```
link_to(name, '#', onclick: "add_fields(this, '#{association}', '#{escape_javascript(fields)}')")
```